# Displaying mySQL result to textbox

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to select the user email from a mySQL database, and then display the result in a textbox. However, I get an error message:
htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

```
<?php

    if(!isset($_SESSION)){
        session_start();
    }

    include "config.php";

    $q = "SELECT email FROM users WHERE id ='" . $_SESSION['id'] . "'";
    $result = $sql->query($q);
    $user_email = $result->fetch_assoc();

    $link->close();

?>

    <input class="form" type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo html entities($user_email); ?>" />
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should use prepared statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your result is an array and not a string. what you can do:

```
<?php

    if(!isset($_SESSION)){
        session_start();
    }

    include "config.php";

    $q = "SELECT email FROM users WHERE id ='" . $_SESSION['id'] . "'";
    $result = $sql->query($q);
    $user_email = $result->fetch_assoc();

    $resultText = '';
    $glue = '</br>' . PHP_EOL;
    foreach($user_email as $email) {
        $resultText .= $email . $glue;
    }

    $link->close();

?>

    <input class="form" type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo htmlentities($resultText); ?>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

`fetch_assoc` returns the row.

try:

```
$user_email['enter_the_mysql_field_name_here']
```